# How to enable connector line jumps

Tags: enterprise-architect, domain-model

I have a domain model, which when unions intersect, looks like this:

[image]

What I want to do is that, when two lines intersect, that one pass over the other, like the following:

[image]

Supposedly this should be done by the Enterprise by default, but it doesn't.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **Start | Desktop | Preferences | Diagram** and set the option **Enable Connector line jumps** <sub>(valid for version 15.1)</sub>

[image]